# Can I treat an object as implementing an interface from reflection?

Tags: c#, dll, reflection, interface

I am trying to load types from a DLL that all implement an interface. I want to be able to get the types from the DLL, create and instance of each type and then treat each type as if it implements the interface. I have written a basic example below of what I'm trying to achieve.

Thanks for your help

```
    class Program
    {
        private static List<IJob> _jobs; 

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LoadJobs();

            foreach (var job in _jobs)
            {
                job.Run();
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void LoadJobs()
        {
            _jobs = new List<IJob>();

            var jobsPath = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Jobs\");

            foreach (var file in jobsPath)
            {
                var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(file);

                foreach (var type in assembly.GetExportedTypes())
                {
                   var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                   var job = instance as IJob;

                    if(job != null)
                        _jobs.Add(job);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are mixing two concepts. `type` is a `Type` you're treating it as instance. `type as IJob` is never going to be true.

Comment: If you want to check if a *type implements interface* you can do it like that: `type.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IJob))`

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add in the instance before I posted. I don't know if this is still possible or not.

Comment: @Dmitry If I use that it just returns a bool. I want to be able to call methods from the instance that are from the interface it implements.

Comment: @DanMarionette: to be able *to call methods* (which are not static ones in your case) you *have to create an instance(s)* and so you have to call *constructor(s)*

Comment: @Dmitry I have edited the code to create an instance, but the 'as' keyword still returns null. Have I not created the instance properly?

Comment: @DanMarionette: do you really want to create an isntance *of every type* mentioned in the Assembly? Check if type implements the interface first (see my suggestion above), and only then create an instance. Be sure, that type has an *apropriate constructor* (public one, without parameters in your case) for `Activator` can use it

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var type in assembly.GetExportedTypes().Where(t => t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof (IJob))))
{
    var job = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IJob;
    if(job != null) _jobs.Add(job);
}
```